# Bringing in SQL data and creating lots of PivotTables - looking for a way to eliminate the need to reference each pivottable in the code

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Background: I have a workbook with a lot of tabs that’s brings in data from SQL database (please see example query below). And due to a lot of reasons, I need to create many pivot tables in each tab because each pivot table needs to look at one particular set of data. Every-time I create a pivot table I have to go to “Pivot Table Options” and jot down the pivottable number and then update the VBA code with the appropriate sequential code `Set pvt = Me.PivotTables("PivotTable###")`.

Questions: Is there some VBA code that can reference all the pivot tables within each tab without the need to reference a pivotable number? Cause I have a lot of tabs and I need to create a lot of pivot tables and I’m losing track of the pivotable numbers.

```
Sub RefreshData()
    Dim SQl As String
    Dim startDATE As String, endDATE As String
    Dim pvt As PivotTable

    Set pvt = Me.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    Set pvt = Me.PivotTables("PivotTable2")
    Set pvt = Me.PivotTables("PivotTable3")

    'pvt.PivotCache.Connection = "ODBC;DSN=" & Application.Range("DSN_Source") & ";DATABASE=" & Application.Range("T123") & ";"

    startDATE = Format(Me.Range("SDate"), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
    endDATE = Format(Me.Range("EDate"), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")

    SQl = ""

    SQl = "WITH ABC As " & vbCrLf
    SQl = SQl & "( " & vbCrLf
    SQl = SQl & "  SELECT Stuff  " & vbCrLf
    SQl = SQl & ", more stuff,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RIGHT(Stuff, 2) " & vbCrLf
    SQl = SQl & ", stuff1, stuff2, stuff3 ORDER BY Estuff4 DESC) As RowNum" & vbCrLf

    SQl = SQl & " FROM StuffTable " & vbCrLf

    SQl = SQl & " WHERE stuff = 'stuffy'  AND " & vbCrLf


    *snip


    With pvt.PivotCache
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = SQl
    End With
    pvt.RefreshTable



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through all the PivotTables like so:

```
For Each pvt In Me.PivotTables
    With pvt.PivotCache
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Sql
    End With
    pvt.RefreshTable
Next
```